# Use Cassandra for adserver both master and analytical data

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, advertisement-server, nosql

Hi we are planning to use Cassandra for ad server implementation. We have a req where client can create advertisers publishers and new ads sort of typical relational req as well as interface to monitor analytical data ad hits, conversion etc. We also needs an interface where client is able to apply filters based on master fields such as name, location etc. As well as based on analytical data like where ad revenue > x and similar other criterias quite a few in nos.

Is it OK to use a single databases like Cassandra to maintain both types of data. As Cassandra has fairly limited  querying capacity on fields unless u create views n index we are skeptical. If we keep two seperate databases products will it complicate and add additional redundancy. How companies such as Facebook, linkedin are accounting for both master and analytical data req. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution in Cassandra is to have multiple datacenters - one for online transaction processing, and another for spark analytical queries. The different datacenters allow you to query them independently so spark doesn't impact production. Alternatively you can denormalize and insert into multiple tables using 'BaTCH'